# view to work for particular set of taxonomy terms

Tags: 7, views

Case: I have a taxonomy vocabulary namely 'categories'. It consists of some parent terms with their child terms as shown.

```
 Parent1

 -p1child-1

 -p1child-2

 Parent2

  -p2child-1

  -p2child-2
```

I want to create a view which work only for a particular set.

Suppose in this case I will create 2 views, each for both parent terms and both will have different set of exposed filters and sort criteria.

So if I visited `taxonomy/term/parent1` or `taxonomy/term/p1child-1` or  `taxonomy/term/p2child-2`, it would render that specific view of parent1.

is it possible ?

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give [Taxonomy Views Integrator](https://www.drupal.org/project/tvi) module a try.

> The TVI (Taxonomy Views Integrator) module allows selective overriding
>   of taxonomy terms and/or vocabulary with the view of your choice.
>   Using TVI you can easily create custom views to output all terms in X
>   vocabuarly.
>
> TVI will try not to interfere with views or taxonomy/term page
>   displays if no TVI views exist for the current page request.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for :)