# How to show different view templates for different taxonomy terms?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I'm using Drupal 7, and I had a vocabulary "Destinations". Under this vocabulary, I had terms with 2 levels. For example:

- ASEAN
  -- Brunei
  -- Indonesia
  -- Laos
- EUROPE
  -- Spain
  -- Greence
  -- Portugal

For all 1st level taxonomy terms of this vocabulary (ASEAN, EUROPE), I want to display them as a view, with child taxonomy. Eg:

- ASEAN
  -- Brunei  (term name & description)
  -- Indonesia  (term name & description)
  -- Laos (term name & description)
- EUROPE
  -- Spain  (term name & description)
  -- Greence  (term name & description)
  -- Portugal (term name & description)

For all 2nd level taxonomy terms, I want to display nodes which have the term. Eg:

- Brunei
  -- Package 1
  -- Package 2
- Spain
  -- Package 3
  -- Package 4

Is there any way I can configure the views to display result as above?
It might have something to do with contextual filter, but I don't know how to configure the parameters.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: I think you are looking for http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/163468/view-to-work-for-particular-set-of-taxonomy-terms

Answer (score 0):

in child tpl of views taxonomy term check the parent of tid. if parent value is 0 then show data like "Brunei (term name & description)"
And if parent not 0 then show like "Package 1"